# Доступ только определенному порту для интерфейса (eth:x)

Tags: linux, iptables, udp, firewall

Здравствуйте, встрял в проблему, что нужно ограничить подключения к одному порту определенного интерфейса на выделенном сервере.
Имеем:

- IP адрес;
- Сервис, работающий с UDP трафиком на xxxxx порту;

Вопрос состоит в следующем: как сформировать правило для iptables, чтобы к определенному IP (eth0:x) можно было подключиться только по UDP к xxxx порту (tcp портов не должно быть)

Comment: *-p tcp -j DENY*?

Comment: @0andriy, лучше дроп, мыж скрываем сервисы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp -d tut_opredelennii_ip_address --dport tut_opredelennii_port -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -d tut_opredelennii_ip_address -j DROP
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло в решении проблемы)